# Forbid uninstall and data clearing

Tags: android, uninstallation

I try to develop a high security app
some options are :

1. Uninstallable
2. only uninstall from app with security code
3. unable to clear data
4. <strike>start on boot</strike>   Solved
5. <strike>run in background</strike>  Solved
6. run if close forced
7. <strike>can't connect to internet</strike> Solved
8. recovery data if it lost

App has admin rights

minimum api is 16

some one has any idea

tnx sorry for my bad English

Comment: for 7) in your service check if network connection made, disconnect it

Comment: For 1 & 2 read this it will help you.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html

Comment: tnx for 2 but for 1 this is for api 21 don't support my app